# data driven support for mobile automation

Tags: android, robotium

I would like to know whether Robotium supports data-driven testing if so please provide useful links and methods.

Comment: I know that it possible to use Java API inside Robotium tests. Establish connections, get data from DB, etc, so I think you can.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible . Android has inbuilt SQLite database. You can use that to drive the data for your test sets